# Creating a area around the css button

Tags: css

Okay so I am currently using this for my `<a>` tags in HTML, and here is my css for it

```
#button {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 5px;
  width: auto;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  text-decoration:none;
  color: gray;
}
#button:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

But sadly the buttons are bigger then a standard line and just overlap eachother, for example:
Here is some text [button]
here is some more text [button]

Where the [button]s is beneath/ontop of the other it overlaps in the browser, (if that makes sense)

Here is a screenshot: [image: screenshot]

How can I make it so it creates a kind of area around it where it cant overlap and will push other elements outwards or so, margin seems to not work (top and bottom does nothing) and padding seems to make the 1px border bigger in height, thanks!

Comment: With that css you can be formatting only one button (because ids have to be unique within a document). Apart from that, maybe `display:inline-block` solves your issue. (If not, then please deliver a _real_ problem description.)

Comment: @CBroe Ah thanks! it works fine with that! The margin works now with that too, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add
    display:inline-block;
to your button selector, e.g.:

```
#button {
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-bottom-width: 5px;
        width: auto;
        padding-left: 2px;
        padding-right: 2px;
        text-decoration:none;
        color: gray;
        display:inline-block;
    }
```

As an aside, i'd recommend that button is a class rather than an id, because you shouldn't really have multiple elements with the same id on the same page.

Comment: Okay, I'm new to CSS, I wasn't sure the huge difference between id's and class', I will make sure I keep it in mind, thank you very much!

Comment: No problem! If there are multiple elements with the same ID on a page everything would work perfectly, but it technically isn't valid html and would fail if you put it through an html validator.  The html validator at http://validator.w3.org/ is a useful tool if you're interested.  Id is used if you want to reference a specific element, and class is used if you have many elements with similar styling. An element can have an id and a class, depending on the situation.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The distance between the lines in your example is too short to display a Button-Text surrounded by border with space that fits into that line.

So I sugesst to increase the `line-height` of the default Text.

Here an example: [JSFiddle-Example](http://jsfiddle.net/QW84L/)